# How can I tell which process is using sensors

Tags: android, performance

I'm trying to track down a power consumption issue. I know that *something* out there is using sensors while the device is quietly lying on its back with the screen blank, but I can't tell what.

Is there a way to find out what process is using sensors? (Gravity, in this case.)